# how to update data in laravel rest api with email not by id

Tags: laravel

controller code

```
function restUpdateByemail(Request $request,$email){

            $students=student::find($email);
            $students->name =$request->input("name");
            $students->password=$request->input("password");
            $students->gender=$request->input("gender");
            $students->country=$request->input("country");
            $students->save();
            return response()->json($students);


        }
```

Comment: Try this $students = student::where('email', $email)->first();

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function restUpdateByemail(Request $request,$email){

                $students=student::where('email',$email)->first();
                $students->name =$request->input("name");
                $students->password=$request->input("password");
                $students->gender=$request->input("gender");
                $students->country=$request->input("country");
                $students->save();
                return response()->json($students);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well

```
 function restUpdateByemail(Request $request,$email) {

          $students = student::where('email',$email)->first();

          $students->update($request->all());

          return response()->json($students);
 }
```